# A problem on linear operator: what does the bounded operator mean?

Tags: operator-theory, compact-operators

I'm puzzled in the bounded operator concept. Now I want to ask a simple problem about that.

If $I$ is an indexing set, $\{T_\alpha|\alpha\in I\}$ is a linear bounded operator collection from $X$ to $X_1$, where $X, X_1$ are normed spaces. Based on the above fact, I list some conclusions:

1. For $\forall T_\alpha,$ there exists a constant $M_\alpha\ge0$, such that $\forall x\in X$,
   $$\|T_\alpha x\|\le M_\alpha\|x\|$$ holds.
2. For $\forall T_\alpha$, I have $$ \sup_{\alpha}\|T_\alpha x\|\lt \infty. $$

I want to know whether the above two conclusions are right. where is the mistake? Could someone tell?

Comment: The first conclusion is true, almost as a direct meaning of a bounded operator. The second one is false. Consider the operators $T_n$ where $T_nx=nx$. For $x\neq 0$, the supremum is infinite.

Comment: Yeah, you have the point. Thanks! But I want to ask you: if I change the condition of Banach - Steinhaus theorem to $\forall \alpha\in I$, there is $$\|T_\alpha\|<M_{x}$$ holding. Can we come that final conclusion?

Comment: The condition doesn't really make much sense. This is because you are saying that for each $\alpha$, the operator $T_\alpha$ has an upper bound that depends on...$x$? But $x$ is not defined in regards to $T_\alpha$.

Comment: Sorry, It's my fault, I meant $\|T_\alpha x\|<M_x$, where $M_x $ is a nonnegative constant.